# Meaning of "job" in this context

Tags: meaning

This passage comes from Word Smart:

> Warren's female employees are victims of sexual harassment. If people
>   outside his company ever find out about Warren's record of sexual
>   harassment, he'll never be able to get another ***job***. Good!

I'd like to know the exact meaning of ***job*** in the last sentence.
Here's what I thought.
I don't think it means a position in general sense in this context.
Since he is an employer a job here seems to mean a person who want to be employed or who he want to employ. He cannot be a person who want to be employed.
But my problem is I cannot find that specific meaning in a few dictionaries I have checked.

Comment: If Warren is an employer, and it is his own company, it could mean that he will never get another "job" in the sense of a contract. For example if he is a jobbing builder, no one will ever employ his company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the word ***job*** does indeed refer to a *A paid position of regular employment* although it is being used more broadly to signify any sort of work, either as an employee or as the owner of a company with which no one wants to do business.

For example, many people do not eat at Chick-fil-a (a popular chain of chicken sandwich restaurants in the US) because of their vocal opposition to marriage equality.  Similarly, in this case, other companies would not do business with Warren's company because of his sexual harrassment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In that case, Can I say Chich-fil-a would have a hard time to get any job or employee for their vocal opposition to marriage equality?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly analogous; Chick-fil-a is a retail business (dealing with customers, not so much other businesses), but, yes, they've lost customers (I won't eat there) and potential employees (I know people who wouldn't work there) because of their stance.  I inferred, perhaps incorrectly, that Warren's company was more of a business-to-business organization -- that is, they do work (or _**jobs**_ even) for other companies.  But bear in mind, also, that sometimes people who were (or even are) owners of one company do get jobs working for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean a position -- perhaps he anticipates that disclosure of his improprieties would result in going out of business, so he would cease being an owner and would have to try to get a job as an employee.

But if his company performs work on contract, *job* can refer to an order for work. This is definition #2 at [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/job):

> A task or piece of work, especially one that is paid.